# How do I attach to the modal closed event from bootstrap 4 via Jquery in a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vuejs2

I have a Vue JS project where I've referenced Bootstrap 4 in the index.html page, as well as Jquery. I also have JQuery included via npm. I know there's so much wrong with that, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

That said, I'm trying to capture/hook/listen to the modal closing event. I've created the modals as components that are only rendered if a certain object exists in the vuex store. I've tried all of the following in both the parent component and the child component that is the modal in question. Nothing I've tried so far seems to work.

Any suggestions will be most welcome.

In the  tags of the component:

```
jq(document).ready(function() {
    jq('#EditContactModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('MODAL HIDDEN');
        //this.ModalCanceled();
    });
});

jq('#EditContactModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('MODAL HIDDEN');
    //this.ModalCanceled();
});
```

One thing I did try that sort of works is:

```
jq(document).ready(function() {
    jq('body').on('click', '#EditContactModal', function () {
        // this.Close();
        this.newEmployee = null;
        this.$store.dispatch('setSelectedContact', null);
    });
});
```

However, this last bit has the interesting issue of throwing a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined" error. It's like I can't use any of the vue objects within any of the JQuery code.

**** Edit 1 - solution per Satyam Pathak's comments ****

So Satyam's answer is exactly what I needed. I've implemented this in 2 ways and am going back and forth on which way is better practice. I honestly don't know.

The first add the following to my EditContactModal component:

```
    created() {
        jq(document).on('hide.bs.modal', () => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            // console.log('MODAL HIDDEN');
            this.newEmployee = null;
            this.$store.dispatch('setSelectedContact', null);
        });
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        //remove listener since it's attached to the document and will remain even after
        //this component is destroyed
        jq(document).off('hide.bs.modal');
    },
```

For whatever reason, providing the '#EditContactModal' selector doesn't work. The event is never attached properly. So, I have to attach the listener to the document. This is done in the Created() event. An interesting side effect is that even though the component is destroyed because the 'setSelectedContact' mutator is called, the listener still exists. That means every time the component is recreated another one is attached. To address this, I added the code in the beforeDestroy() to unattach the listener from the document.

All of this works fine.

Another solution I tried is handling this in the parent component, which happens to be my App.vue component. Here is that code:

```
    created() {
        jq(document).on('hide.bs.modal', () => {
            this.$store.dispatch('setSelectedContact', null);
            this.$store.dispatch('setSelectedAddress', null);
        });
    }
```

The application has 2 components that work as modals so that's why there are 2 statements there. This seems the cleaner option of the two.

I do wish I could get the '#EditContactModal' selector working, but I'm guessing this doesn't work due to life cycle issues in how the component is rendered in App.vue. What I mean is this:

```
<EditContactModal v-if="this.selectedContact"></EditContactModal>
```

So, when there isn't a "selectedContact" object in the store, there is no EditContactModal div created on the page. For now, I think I'm fine with keeping this in the App.vue, but I'm certainly open to any further thoughts on the subject.

Lastly, I rather do like the suggestion of emitting the modal closed event to the parent. That said, I'd still have to attach to the document for the listener, which also means I'll need to unattach the listener from the component. Given that, and that I have 2 such components that do this, it's simplest to just leave the code in the App.vue component.

Comment: I never used jquery along with vue, the above closing modal method exist in any component ?  and you want to listen whenever the modal get closed ? Is this your question ?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely it. I'm actually using Bootstrap and Jquery and Vue, which seems heavy handed to me, but I'm just getting started. I know the Bootstrap modal emits a series of events, but I wasn't sure how to connect my Vue component with the 'hide.bs.modal' event. I was close to the right answer, but wouldn't have gotten it without your post talking about lexical scope. I'll grant the bounty tomorrow (I'm not allowed for the first 24 hours after posting it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a modal component `Modal` and inside it you attach this listener

```
jq(document).ready(function() {
    jq('#EditContactModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('MODAL HIDDEN');
        //this.ModalCanceled();
    });
});

jq('#EditContactModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('MODAL HIDDEN');
    //this.ModalCanceled();
});
```

You probably doing the above attachment in `created/mounted` hook of the component.

> this last bit has the interesting issue of throwing a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined" error. It's like I can't use any of the vue objects within any of the JQuery code.

**To fix the above problem**

You need to remove dynmaic scoping from your methods so that `this` refers to `vue` to make your dispatch code work. Change `function` declaration to `arrow functions` to lexically bind it.

```
jq(document).ready(() =>{
    jq('body').on('click', '#EditContactModal',  () => {
        this.newEmployee = null;
        this.$store.dispatch('setSelectedContact', null);
        // Now you won't get the error
    });
});
```

Now the above correction will fix your problem of `dispatching` a store `action`.

I also want to introduce `emitting` events from components when you want to move up in component `hierarchy`

`Modal` component can emit an `event` to notify `parent` component about something

Ex - In your `Modal` component

```
jq(document).ready(() => {
    jq('#EditContactModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
        this.$emit('modalClosed')
    });
});
```

Now this will notify your `Parent` component

In parent you can listen it

`<Modal @modalClosed="doSomething()" />`

Let me know in comments if you need any more specific information

Comment: Wow. I've been struggling for a week off and on trying to figure this out. I didn't know about how () => binds the "this" keyword to the context where the function is being called. That fixed the issue. Now I'm struggling over what exactly would be a best practice. I'll update my answer to explain. That said, you'll most likely get the bounty as this was exactly the information I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :) Actually the other way or say practice is to use eventbus but trust me the pattern you are using is more helpful which is using vuex. In eventbus u need to take care of listeners alot. Just try avoid using jquery in future components and you are good to go